# Java web session cookie path issue with a web server as load balancer

Tags: java, http, proxy, nginx, web

I have a Java Web project, 
Nginx as the http proxy,
Tomcat as the back-end Servlet Container.

An app that deployed on the Tomcat has a Context Path and it runs like http://localhost:8080/project-name

I show that project to the users like this: www.project-name.com
with: proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/project-name/

I'm using a session in the Java Web project and that session is handled by a cookie sent with the name JSESSIONID.

The problem is JSESSIONID has a cookie path with /project-name/ and the browser can't access that because the user is NOT browsing www.project-name.com/project-name/

Do you know what is the best practice here to get over this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

Look for `sessionCookieDomain`, `sessionCookieName` and `sessionCookiePath`.

Comment: Do you think this makes any problems due to fact that jsession will be shared(?) among other apps in the same server?

Comment: I'm not sure sharing a JSESSIONID would be a problem as the webapps shouldn't be able to see each other's session data. Unless you used `crossContext=true`. But I haven't tested this.